# Recursion "Word Warp" program in Java

Tags: java, loops, recursion, arraylist, intellij-idea

I have to write a program that does the following:

> *Your program will read in several lines of text. Your program will reformat each
>   line into smaller lines that are no more than 20 characters each. If a word would make the line extend past 20 characters, the entire word should be shifted to the next line. A word consists of a string of characters that does not contain a space. Words may be made up of letters, digits, and/or punctuation marks. You will be guaranteed that no word in the input is larger than 20 characters.The input will consist of several lines of text. There will be at least one word in
>   each line. The input will be terminated with a line consisting of the text "END”. Your program should output a formatted set of lines for each line of text in input. A blank line will separate each set of lines.*

I've written the program and it's outputting what it's supposed to be outputting but for some reason, it's repeating certain lines and I can't figure out why.

**Input:**

```
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
12345678901234567890
Did you see the game in Lane Stadium? 
I hear we won.
LSU fans sob. Virginia Tech fans rejoice. One more victory.
END
```

**My program's output:**

```
The quick brown fox
jumped over the lazy
dog.
jumped over the lazy dog.
12345678901234567890
Did you see the game
in Lane Stadium? I
hear we won.
in Lane Stadium? I hear we won.
LSU fans sob.
Virginia Tech fans
rejoice. One more
victory.
rejoice. One more victory.
Virginia Tech fans rejoice. One more victory.
```

**What it should be:**

```
The quick brown fox
jumped over the lazy
dog.
12345678901234567890
Did you see the game
in Lane Stadium? I
hear we won.
LSU fans sob.
Virginia Tech fans
rejoice. One more
victory.
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input;
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a line of input or END to exit: ");
        input = console.nextLine();
        if (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("END")) {
            lines.add(input);
        }
    } while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("END"));

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        String line = lines.get(i);
        line(line);
    }
}

public static int stopIndex(String s) {
    int stop = 0;
    for (int k = 20; k >= 0; k--) {
        if (s.charAt(k) == ' ') {
            stop = k;
            break;
        }
    }
    return stop;
}

public static void line(String line) {
    String finalLine;
    String finalLine2;
    if (line.length() > 20) {
           if (line.charAt(20) != ' ') {
                int stop = stopIndex(line);
                finalLine = line.substring(0, stop);
                finalLine2 = line.substring(stop + 1, line.length());
            } else {
                finalLine = line.substring(0, 20);
                finalLine2 = line.substring(21, line.length());
            }
    } else {
        finalLine = line.substring(0, line.length());
        finalLine2 = "";
    }
    System.out.println(finalLine);
    if (finalLine2.length() > 20) {
        line(finalLine2);
    }
    if (finalLine2.equals("")) {
        System.out.print(finalLine2);
    } else {
        System.out.println(finalLine2);
    }
}
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you look at your output the duplicated lines are violating your 20 character restriction. With that in mind you should look at when you are doing prints in your recursion and see if that gives you something to go on.

Comment: Do you mean 'word wrap'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is in the "line" method:

```
    if (finalLine2.length() > 20) {
        line(finalLine2);
    }
    if (finalLine2.equals("")) {
        System.out.print(finalLine2);
    } else {
        System.out.println(finalLine2);
    }
```

here you print it once(by calling the line method):

```
if (finalLine2.length() > 20) {
            line(finalLine2);
}
```

then you print it again:

```
if (finalLine2.equals("")) {
       System.out.print(finalLine2);
} else {
       System.out.println(finalLine2);
}
```

try changing it to:

```
if (finalLine2.length() > 20) {
    line(finalLine2);
}
else {
    System.out.println(finalLine2);
}
```

Comment: deleting the second part will fix it

Comment: When I deleted the second part, it omits part of the message. For example, if I type in the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog, I get "The quick brown fox / jumped over the lazy" and the word dog is missing.

Comment: got it... just change that part to:  "else { System.out.println(finalLine2); } @ch1maera

Answer (score 0):

Your `public static void line(String line)` method contains 3 `println` statements.  The first will always be executed, and then the second or the third will be executed, so you will get at most 2 lines printed for each input line.

`LSU fans sob. Virginia Tech fans rejoice. One more victory.` contains more than 2 sets of 20 character spans; a maximum of two `println` calls won't do.

You might want to try making the logic use a loop.

Hint follows:

> Change:
>      `if (line.length() > 20) {`
>  to something like more like:
>      `while (line.length() > 20) {`
>  and ditch the recursion.